# Automated way of defining hierarchic structure in fabletools::aggregate_key

Tags: r, time-series, fable-r

I'm looking for an automated way to declare the `.spec`-part from `aggregate_key`, starting from a vector of strings containing the names of the variables linked to the different levels.

The following of course doesn't work, but everything I tried with adding `!!as.name()` or using `do.call`, ended in failure.

```
levels <- paste( c("L1",'L2','L3'), collapse = '/')

mytsibble %>% aggregate_key(levels, value = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabletools::aggregate_key()` supports tidyverse style `!!` operations for non-standard evaluation.

This allows you to construct the expression however you like, and use it within `aggregate_key()` using `!!expression`.

For example, using `rlang::parse_expr()` to convert a string into an expression:

```r
library(fpp3)
tourism %>% 
  aggregate_key(Purpose*(State/Region), Trips = sum(Trips))
#> # A tsibble: 34,000 x 5 [1Q]
#> # Key:       Purpose, State, Region [425]
#>    Quarter Purpose      State        Region        Trips
#>      <qtr> <chr*>       <chr*>       <chr*>        <dbl>
#>  1 1998 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 23182.
#>  2 1998 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20323.
#>  3 1998 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19827.
#>  4 1998 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20830.
#>  5 1999 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22087.
#>  6 1999 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 21458.
#>  7 1999 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19914.
#>  8 1999 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20028.
#>  9 2000 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22339.
#> 10 2000 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19941.
#> # … with 33,990 more rows

levels <- rlang::parse_expr("Purpose*(State/Region)")
tourism %>% 
  aggregate_key(.spec = !!levels, Trips = sum(Trips))
#> # A tsibble: 34,000 x 5 [1Q]
#> # Key:       Purpose, State, Region [425]
#>    Quarter Purpose      State        Region        Trips
#>      <qtr> <chr*>       <chr*>       <chr*>        <dbl>
#>  1 1998 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 23182.
#>  2 1998 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20323.
#>  3 1998 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19827.
#>  4 1998 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20830.
#>  5 1999 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22087.
#>  6 1999 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 21458.
#>  7 1999 Q3 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19914.
#>  8 1999 Q4 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 20028.
#>  9 2000 Q1 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 22339.
#> 10 2000 Q2 <aggregated> <aggregated> <aggregated> 19941.
#> # … with 33,990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This would work with your example as:

```r
levels <- rlang::parse_expr(paste( c("L1",'L2','L3'), collapse = '/'))
mytsibble %>% aggregate_key(!!levels, value = sum(value))
```

There are more robust ways to construct the expression (incase the variable names contain `*` or `/`), for example you could use `rlang::call2()` with symbols and expressions.

```r
library(rlang)
call2("*", sym("Purpose"), call2("/", sym("State"), sym("Region")))
#> Purpose * (State/Region)
```

Or equivalently (and more compactly) for your always nested example:

```r
purrr::reduce(syms(c("L1",'L2','L3')), call2, .fn = "/")
#> L1/L2/L3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

These expressions can then be used with `aggregate_key()` using `!!` once again.

---

**Why didn't `!!as.name(levels)` work?**

`as.name()` produces a name (in rlang/tidyverse this is known as a 'symbol'), not an expression. A name/symbol can be thought of as a name of an object, or the name of a variable in the data. Using `!!as.name(levels)` will try to produce an aggregation of a column named `"L1/L2/L3"`, not a nested hierachy of columns `"L1"`, `"L2"`, and `"L3"`. For this, you need an expression.